# name 'search' is not defined In Sublime Texte 3 (search of IMAP)

Tags: python, search, imap

i want to downloap PJ from an email so i write this code

```
import imaplib, email, os
from time import sleep

user='my_email'
password = 'secret'
imap_url = 'Outlook.office365.com'


con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)


def get_attachments(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype()=='multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, fileName)
            with open(filePath,'wb') as f:
                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))



attachment_dir = "D:/TOUT/DATANALYSE/email_python/attachement/"

never_stop = True
while never_stop:
    last_email_id = search('FROM', "kvaccarin@datanalyse.fr", con)[0].split()[-1]
    typ, data = con.fetch(last_email_id, '(RFC822)')
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    get_attachments(msg)
    time.sleep(12*60*60)
```

this code works when i run on Jupyter but when i want to run this code with Sublime Texte i have this error:

```
NameError: name 'search' is not defined
```

This fonction search() is not the fonction from re but it's the fonction from IMAP

Someone know how to fix it?

Comment: You need to call it on your connection object.  `con.search`....

Comment: Thanks for your help! That was the issue of my code!  :D

Answer (score 0):

It's the beginning of the answers... but it's something!

Thanks to Max, I understand the error on the first Question, So to fix it I define a new function search_data():

```
def search_data(key,value,con): 
    result, data = con.search(None,key,'"{}"'.format(value)) 
    return data
```

and when I run the same code with the use of this function like that:

```
import imaplib, email, os
from time import sleep

user='my_email'
password = 'secret'
imap_url = 'Outlook.office365.com'


con = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_url)
con.login(user,password)


def get_attachments(msg):
    for part in msg.walk():
        if part.get_content_maintype()=='multipart':
            continue
        if part.get('Content-Disposition') is None:
            continue
        fileName = part.get_filename()

        if bool(fileName):
            filePath = os.path.join(attachment_dir, fileName)
            with open(filePath,'wb') as f:
                f.write(part.get_payload(decode=True))

def search_data(key,value,con):
   result, data  = con.search(None,key,'"{}"'.format(value))
   return data  

attachment_dir = "D:/TOUT/DATANALYSE/email_python/attachement/"

never_stop = True
while never_stop:
    last_email_id = search_data('FROM', "kvaccarin@datanalyse.fr", con)[0].split()[-1]
    typ, data = con.fetch(last_email_id, '(RFC822)')
    msg = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
    get_attachments(msg)
    time.sleep(12*60*60)
```

there still have an error:

```
error: command SEARCH illegal in state AUTH, only allowed in states SELECTED
```

I know it's the beginning of the answer but it perhaps helps to have the entire answer!

Comment: You need to select() a folder before you can search it.